UIKit app crashes at launch with 'NSGenericException' related to UINavigationBar's backdropGroupName ivar (no recent code changes)
I'm encountering an app crash immediately after the launch screen on an existing UIKit app. The app has been live on the App Store for a while, and I haven't made any recent changes to the code. Here's the error message I'm seeing in the console:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Access to UINavigationBar's backdropGroupName ivar is prohibited. This is an application bug'
The app crashes on the launch screen with no significant clues as to what might be causing it. I am using Xcode 16.0 and macOS 14.6.1 and iOS 18.0. Has anyone experienced something similar or have any idea what might be going on?
Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Don't access undocumented private iVar, or you can try this approach to avoid crashing (https://lvv.me/posts/2019/06/09-ios13-ivar-kvc-appbug/). Using private APIs can lead to appstore rejection, guideline prohibits it.
